# Can I put multiple jquery selector in the same command

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two command in jQuery wherein all elements are same but not one.

Commands :

```
$("#abc > .className1 > .className2 > .className3");
$("#pqr > .className1 > .className2 > .className3");
```

Can I join above two commands and make it one ?

Any inputs in this regard are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On option is using the `find` method:

```
$('#abc, #pqr').find('> .className1 > .className2 > .className3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that with comma separated [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("#abc > .className1 > .className2 > .className3, #pqr > .className1 > .className2 > .className3");
```

Answer (score 1):

yes with multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)
https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
$("#abc > .className1 > .className2 > .className3, #pqr > .className1 > .className2 > .className3");
```

Comment: Your answer is exact duplicate of @AdityaSharma answer

Answer (score 0):

You can store children selector in variable and use it in jquery selector.

```
var childs = "> .className1 > .className2 > .className3";
$("#abc"+ childs+", #pqr"+ childs)
// Or
$("#abc"+ childs).add("#pqr"+ childs)
```

```js
var childs = "> .className1 > .className2 > .className3";
$("#abc"+ childs).add("#pqr"+ childs).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">
  <div class="className1">
    <div class="className2">
      <div class="className3">className3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pqr">
  <div class="className1">
    <div class="className2">
      <div class="className3">className3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```